# How to animate objects without limbs?

Tags: rigging

How would you animate/rig a cube which moves with its own body power? 
The cube has no legs. It has to pushes itself while taying stitch to a plane and rotate on its edges.

I tried to manually add Keyframes and change the Pivot Point to the particular corner, but that doesn't work because is not possible to keyframe the pivot of the rotation.

[image: cube]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Could you specify what exactly isn't working? What the difficulties are? Keyframing obect's transformation seems a viable way for the task you are presenting.

Comment: The pivot point changes when I do it manually. Because I can't bake the Pivot Point. You have to try it on your own.

Comment: I think https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZg0F7M1S2A could be a good answer.